# Getting parent ID on child click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryng to get parent id on click with jquery.

My django template is as follows :

```
<table id="archive-table" class="table table-hover table-vcenter">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Make and model</th>
          <th>First registration</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {% for calculation in calculations %}
          <tr data-archive-row class="archive-row" data-calculation-id={{ calculation.id }}>
               <td>{{ calculation.first_registration }}</td>
               <td>{{ calculation.body }}</td>
           </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
</table>
```

And my js is as follows :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#archive-table').on('click', '[data-archive-row]', function (e) {
            var calculation_id = e.target.dataset['calculationId'];
            alert(calculation_id)
        })
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the `dataset['calculationId']` of the parent no matter if I clicked on child.

With my code I'm getting **undefined** in alert. But If I for example add `data-calculation-id={{ calculation.id }}` to one **td** and if I then click on it then I'm getting the right id.

Is there any way to get the id from parent no matter if it's clicked on child or on parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `e.currentTarget`, not `target`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#archive-table').on('click', '[data-archive-row]', function(e) {
    var calculation_id = e.currentTarget.dataset.calculationId;
    alert(calculation_id)
  })
});
```

Since you are delegating event, `e.currentTarget` will be TR element, and target will be whatever you clicked within this TR, maybe TD or something in it.

Another simple solution is to simply use `this` as it will point to TR always in event handler:

```
var calculation_id = this.dataset.calculationId;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery you could use the jQuery method **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)** instead :

```
$('#archive-table').on('click', '[data-archive-row]', function (e) {
     var calculation_id = $(this).data('calculation-id');
     alert(calculation_id)
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#archive-table').on('click', '[data-archive-row]', function (e) {
    var calculation_id = $(this).data('calculation-id');

    console.log(calculation_id);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="archive-table" class="table table-hover table-vcenter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make and model</th>
      <th>First registration</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-archive-row class="archive-row" data-calculation-id='calculation.id'>
      <td>calculation.first_registration</td>
      <td>calculation.body</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is good (I would probably use `this.dataset`) but still it's important to understand difference between `e.target` and `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Right, just I think it's better to not mix pure js with jQuery when we could do the trick just with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check for data-calculation-id on current target and if it is undefined check its parent.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#archive-table').on('click', '[data-archive-row]', function (e) {
            var calculation_id = e.currentTarget.dataset['calculationId']
                                 || e.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset['calculationId'];
            alert(calculation_id)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain the point of this part `|| e.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset['calculationId']` ? Because `e.currentTarget` will always be `tr[data-archive-row]`.

Comment: OP asked to use the data-calculationId of the parent if the current target does not have one defined.

Comment: I think OP was trying to workaround problem of using `e.target` which would indeed give undefined for TD and we would need to step one level up. But in your solution it doesn't make sense, because currentTarget guaranties to be TR.